# Angular2 Event for Change detection for Directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have an AuthService which logs in/out, checks if the user is logged and works with `angular2-jwt` (for example uses `tokenNotExpired()`).

I created a Module only for this service to use it as a singleton.

Now I check if the user is logged in for example with this:

```
<p *ngIf="authService.authenticated()">Text</p>
```

Which works as expected.

Now what I want to achieve is to wrap this `*ngIf` into a own directive so that the components checking if the user is logged in, don't have to inject the AuthService.

Basically like this:

```
<p *authenticated>Text</p>
```

I have created the authenticated directive like this:

```
@Directive({selector: "[authenticated]"})
export class AuthenticatedDirective {

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
                private auth: AuthService) {
    }

    @Input() set authenticated(condition: boolean) {
        if (this.auth.authenticated()) {
            console.log("IsLoggedIn");
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            console.log("NotLoggedIn");
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }

}
```

It is basically the *ngIf directive, only that it doesn't use the parameter.

The problem is that it only gets called when the site is loaded, it doesn't check `this.auth.authenticated()` regularly to see if the token is expired.

Triggering the change detection of course doesn't do anything if the directive doesn't listen for it, so manually triggering (for example, after a logout) it doesn't work.

I know that you can "listen" (with host or HostListeners) for events in the directive, but I can't find the event for the change detection, with which I could trigger the directive to "update".

So basically my question is, how can I listen to the change detection event or is there a better solution for wrapping this `*ngIf="authService.authenticated()"`?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

With the comment from @Chrillewoodz I finally remembered lifecycle hooks, especially the mentioned DoCheck.

My current solution for the directive is now this:

```
@Directive({selector: "[authenticated]"})
export class AuthenticatedDirective implements DoCheck {

    private isAuthenticated = false;

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
                private auth: AuthService) {
    }


    ngDoCheck() {
        if (this.isAuthenticated !== this.auth.authenticated()) {
            this.isAuthenticated = this.auth.authenticated();
            if (this.auth.authenticated()) {
                console.log("IsLoggedIn");
                this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            } else {
                console.log("NotLoggedIn");
                this.viewContainer.clear();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `DoCheck` is probably your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the way your directive is written you would need use your directive like

```
<p *authenticated="isAuthenticated">Text</p>
```

Where `isAuthenticated` returns `true` or `false` (whether or not your are authenticated)

I think instead of polling `authService.authenticated()` you should add an observable to `authService` that notifies about.

```
@Directive({selector: "[authenticated]"})
export class AuthenticatedDirective {

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
                private auth: AuthService) {
        auth.isAuthenticated.subscribe(authenticated => {
          if (authenticated()) {
              console.log("IsLoggedIn");
              this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
          } else {
              console.log("NotLoggedIn");
              this.viewContainer.clear();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html shows some nice examples about how to create services with observables.

Comment: Thanks for the (again) quick answer. DoCheck in the comment of my question works for now.

In this case I already tried to work with observables/subscriptions, it didn't work back then for my case, maybe I did something wrong, but I guess angular didn't really get that the directive changed.

Do you think a subscription is a better solution than using the DoCheck hook?

Comment: Definitely. `ngDoCheck` can be called hundreds or thousands of times. You can imagine that this is quite inefficient for something that usually changes less than 10 times during an application life cycle. With an observable nothing gets called at all until the value changes.

Comment: Makes sense of course...."broadcasting" is way less expensive than polling the check. I tried the astronaut/mission approach (although from my head) with the subjects this morning, it didn't update the view. I will try again tomorrow and comment here or edit my question if it worked or not.

Comment: Might be worth a new question as well.

Comment: Ok, got it to work with an Observable, I setup an Intervall with (setInterval()) which checks every 10 seconds if the token is expired, if so it broadcasts the currentstate to the directives. It also broadcasts after a login/logout. It is not perfect yet, but basically it works. Thanks for your input.